# Create dynamic objects python

Tags: python, class, dynamic

For training, I want to atumaticly create users in a system using class.

Here is my code:

```
class CsrUser(object):
    def __init__(self, f_name, l_name, login, role, sex, password ='Hot12345'):
        self.f_name = f_name
        self.l_name = l_name
        self.login = login
        self.role = role
        self.sex = sex
        self.password = password
```

I want to create dynamic objects of the class from the user input,

```
#i want to create something like this
def get_users_data():
    new_user = input("Enter the user name")
    ... #get all the data
    new_user = CsrUser(...)
```

I want the name of the object to be the value that inside new_user

Comment: With the name of the object, do you mean the name of the variable referencing the object?

Comment: what is in a local variable name ? As long as it is readable you get the desired output ?

Comment: I think so, i am kind of new with all the class thing. if i create new = Class(). So i want the new to change to the name that i get from the user.

Comment: @karthikr I don't know how many users will be create so i don't want to hard code 20 Classes names. I am sure i think that way only because my lack of experience

Comment: Any variable name is fine, as long as it refers to the right object you are good to go. Dont worry about changing the object variable name

Comment: If i create a loop that make 20 object of my class. how i will separate them? how i will call to object 1 and not object 20?

Comment: Just use `object_list = []` and `object_list[i]`

Comment: If you don't know the names of the variables that your program creates, it will be difficult to reference them in the rest of your code. You need to store the `CsrUser` class instances in some kind of container, like a dictionary or list, that you know at run time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that naming a variable (object in your case) using a variable is a good idea.  If you want to keep track of all of your users by name, you should use a dictionary instead:

```
#make dictionary
user_data = {}

#make a new user object
new_user = CsrUser(...)

#insert your new user object into the dictionary
#use new_user.f_name or new_user.l_name here in place of new_user.name (or combine both)
user_data[new_user.name] = new_user  

#to get a user object out of the dictionary 
a_user = user_data["name_here"]
```

Comment: I want to create 20 users with my class and track which one is what. This is why i though about making a dynamic name

Comment: A dictionary is exactly what you should be using.  I took a look at your profile and your bio says you're studying python, you should get used to using dictionaries.

Comment: I guess i need to study them more. i just don't fully understand the class concept and how to combine them with dictionary.
I will try your solution and to understand your answer and after that i will come back. thanks :-)

Comment: Putting objects in a dictionary is no different than putting integers or strings in a dictionary.  A dictionary works by having key/value pairs.  Read more here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm